# Do your javadocs get compiled into your class files?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

When you compile your `java` files, does it also embed your javadocs and comments into the class file?

For example, if you have large javadocs, does it effect the overall size of your class file? Or does the compiler ignore everything beginning with `//` and `/*` ?

Comment: `@deprecated` in JavaDoc (not to be confused with `@Deprecated`) is used to set a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There are several debug options that affect the size of a class file but the comments are never part of the resulting `.class` file.

Some estimate:

- `-g:line` just adds line number information (a few bytes)
- `-g:vars` includes the full names of all variables. This is usually the most expensive option.
- `-g:source` just adds the name of the source file (without path).

Note: `-parameters` makes names of method parameter accessible via reflection. This is independent of `-g:vars`.

Comments (and therefore JavaDoc) are never added to the bytecode.

To see what ends up in the `.class` file, use `javap -v` plus the path of the file.

Comment: Have you tried that? JavaDocs are not included even if `-g:source` is set. I tried to decompile classes with JAD.

Comment: @ctapobep: I just tried with Java 6 and 7 and you're right: `-g:source` doesn't include the source code in the class file. A few minutes of prodding and googling didn't turn up why or what this option really does :-/

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is simply wrong.   Java source code, comments or javadocs are never included in the `.class` file.  The `-g:source` option just causes the compiler to emit the (stripped) source file path as an attribute in the `.class` file constant pool.

Comment: @StephenC I can't delete it since it's already accepted. Let's fix it. What is a "stripped source path"?

Comment: It is (AFAIK) basically the pathname for the source file with some prefix removed.  I'd need to deep dive the code again to figure out exactly what that prefix is / how it is determined.  It would be reasonable not include the detail about stripping ... because we are actually talking about something that *doesn't* do what the OP wants (or wants to avoid).

Comment: @StephenC I checked with javap. It strips the path from the file name. Since you can determine the folder from the package name, this probably allows to figure out the source file for inner classes and/or when you have more than one class in a single file.

Answer (score 10):

No, comments are not compiled into your class files.  This includes JavaDocs.

Instead, you need to use a JavaDoc tool (like [Sun/Oracle's](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html)) on the source code to generate the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

No, the class file is just binary data.

Annotations *may* be retained (depending on the annotation).

Comments won't affect the size of the class file.