# Include Deprecated Message In Compiled Class File

Tags: java, deprecated

I want to be able to add a deprecation message to my methods so that when the `.class` file is opened the deprecation message is displayed. Ideally this message would be used to direct the users of the complied class to the method that replaced the deprecated version.

**Source Java File**

```java
/**
 * @deprecated This is the message I want displayed in the complied code
 */
@Deprecated
public void someMethod(java.lang.String couponCode) { 
    this.x++; 
}
```

**Compiled Class File**

The code below is what is currently being displayed when I open the `.class` file using *Intellij 12*

```java
/**
 * @deprecated
 */
@java.lang.Deprecated
public void someMethod(java.lang.String couponCode) { /* compiled code */ }
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4135070/935079

Comment: @jambriz this is not specific to javadocs.

Comment: ok, agreed. but what about the accepted answer, specifically this bit: 'You can tell the compiler to include the sources in the class file (javac -g:source). That means every bit of the source will be added. Comments, code, whitespace, everything.'

Comment: @jambriz true, but I don't want all the sources included. I only want to suggest an alternative approach to the end user, something along the lines of "Constructors are deprecated in favor of factory methods".

Comment: This would be helpful with huge build jobs if you could search for a custom string (e.g. a jira ticket number).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are out of luck.

The `Deprecated` annotation does not have any attributes, so there's nowhere to store any message in the annotation.  And comments (e.g. javadocs) are discarded / not included when a ".java" file is compiled.  In short, there is no way to get the information from a ".class" file created by the standard Java tool chain.

The only way to get the deprecation comment is if the IDE has access to the ".java" file that a ".class" file was compiled from.

(The comment about `javac -g:source` is a bit confused.  The `-g:source` switch causes extra information to be retained, but it is limited to source line numbers and pathnames, names of parameters and stuff like that.  Not the complete source code.  That would be ridiculous ...)

---

I suppose that if you wanted to be inventive, you could create your own custom "deprecation reason" annotation with a message parameter.  Maybe the user's IDE would display it, but that would be IDE specific.  Anyway, it would be worth just trying.

But frankly, why don't you just distribute your code with javadocs or put them on your website?  Surely the programmer needs those anyway!  And anyone with Java experience *knows* that you go to the javadocs to find the explanation of a @deprecation.

(Or better yet - Distribute your source code!  It's a good way to reduce programmer frustration / hatred levels!)